# Availability of channelData for Twilio sms channel for Bot framewok

Tags: twilio, botframework, chatbot, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I am building a bot which handles two channels : Slack and Twilio (SMS).
For sending channel specific messages ,there is one document

[channelData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-channeldata)

I could find channelData for Slack [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder).

But I couldn't find any documentation or link on internet for Twilio.

Guys If you have any hint about this please share..

Here is the sample expected result. for Slack and SMS

[image]

Comment: Is your question how to send MMS with botframework and Twilio?

Comment: @philnash, No, I am able to send it. I need channelData for twilio. Or other ways to send formatted text like list, image...

Comment: There is no way to send formatted text like a list in an SMS. If you want to make a list, then just send line breaks. The way you send images is via MMS which you say you can do.

Comment: I mean I know how to send MMS , but with no sucess. Posted another question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49897741/twilio-mms-status-is-always-remains-sent-when-sent-using-bot-framework

Answer (score 1):

There is no ChannelData specific to Twilio because everything is contained in text and attachments. Why would there be a channelData here?

By the way, for other people coming to this question, if you have to make "channel specific" replies, the 1st thing to use to differenciate replies between channels is to use the `ChannelId` property of the incoming message.

More info:

- Twilio about MMS messages behaviour: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179808-Sending-and-receiving-MMS-messages
- Question about support of MMS in Twilio: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/275

Comment: ..Twilio also supports MMS.. So in that case , there should be a channelData.

Comment: Does the documentation of the Bot Framework says that it supports MMS from Twilio? Twilio also offers voice services, video services, but they are not used in the Bot Framework case. I know it supports kind of MMS because you can send images, but that's not using ChannelData, only Attachments

Comment: I also edited my answer which was a bit too restrictive

Comment: Thanks Nicolas R..but I need some Twilio specific templates which will replicate the slack message. Edited the question for more clarity..

Comment: Your image has a low resolution, it's hard to see details, but as you can see in Channel Inspector here https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/SMS?f=Markdown&e=example1, most of your design needs can't be done with Twilio SMS